# jsoup scraping p tags

Tags: jsoup, screen-scraping

```
<div class="mcsColumnsTwoOne">
    <h1>                     I B D Distribution Ltd                            </h1>
    <p>Certificate Number: NAP 28766</p>
    <p>Date Certified: 08/10/2010</p>

    <p>Consumer Code: RECC</p>
    <p>Membership Number: 00038340</p>

    <h2>Company Address</h2>
    <p>Unit 11 Enterprise Park,Black Moor Road,Verwood,Dorset, BH31 6YS</p>

    <h2>Contact Details</h2>
    <p>Telephone: 01202 825682</p>
        <p>Website: <a href="http://www.ibd-distribution.com" title="                     I B D Distribution Ltd                            ">www.ibd-distribution.com</a></p>
        <p>Email: <span id="cloakc973703bbc5107b52e9fd9a2faf77e96"><a href="mailto:darren@ibd-distribution.com">darren@ibd-distribution.com</a></span><script type="text/javascript">
                document.getElementById('cloakc973703bbc5107b52e9fd9a2faf77e96').innerHTML = '';
                var prefix = '&#109;a' + 'i&#108;' + '&#116;o';
                var path = 'hr' + 'ef' + '=';
                var addyc973703bbc5107b52e9fd9a2faf77e96 = 'd&#97;rr&#101;n' + '&#64;';
                addyc973703bbc5107b52e9fd9a2faf77e96 = addyc973703bbc5107b52e9fd9a2faf77e96 + '&#105;bd-d&#105;str&#105;b&#117;t&#105;&#111;n' + '&#46;' + 'c&#111;m';
                var addy_textc973703bbc5107b52e9fd9a2faf77e96 = 'd&#97;rr&#101;n' + '&#64;' + '&#105;bd-d&#105;str&#105;b&#117;t&#105;&#111;n' + '&#46;' + 'c&#111;m';document.getElementById('cloakc973703bbc5107b52e9fd9a2faf77e96').innerHTML += '<a ' + path + '\'' + prefix + ':' + addyc973703bbc5107b52e9fd9a2faf77e96 + '\'>'+addy_textc973703bbc5107b52e9fd9a2faf77e96+'<\/a>';
        </script></p>
        <p>Contact: Darren Johnson</p>
    <p>Contact Position: Director</p>
    <hr>
    <h2 style="margin: 10px 0 0 0">Contact Installer</h2>

    <form name="contact" action="" method="post" class="formstyle" style="width: 100%">
        <fieldset>
            <p>(<em>*</em>) Denotes required field </p>
            <label for="name">Name <em>*</em></label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text" required="">
            <br class="clear">
            <div class="thepot">
                <label for="emailaddress">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="emailaddress" id="emailaddress">
            </div>
            <label for="email">Email <em>*</em></label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="text" required="">
            <br class="clear">
            <label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
            <input type="tel" name="telephone" id="telephone" class="text">
            <br class="clear">
            <label for="enquiry">Enquiry <em>*</em></label>
            <textarea name="enquiry" id="enquiry" rows="10" cols="10" required=""></textarea>
            <br class="clear">
            <input type="hidden" name="loadtime" value="1515943155">
            <input id="submitbutton" name="submitbutton" value="Submit" type="submit">
            <div class="thepot">
                    <label for="submitForm">submitForm</label>
                    <input type="text" name="submitForm" id="submitForm" value="">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

    </div>**strong text**
```

Am trying to extract data from the above code with java jsoup library , Though am getting error when the 'Contact' p tag is empty, the 'Contact Position' is displayed on 'contact' p tag how do i make the contact column display blank when empty and also keep Contact Position p text on the last column? your help will be much appreciated
.
    for ( Element d : data ) {

```
               idrow++;

         String Consumers = d.select("h1").text();
         String CertificateNumberall = d.select("p:eq(1)").text();
         String CertificateNumber = CertificateNumberall.substring(CertificateNumberall.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
         String DateCertifiedall = d.select("p:eq(2)").text();
         String DateCertified = DateCertifiedall.substring(DateCertifiedall.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
         String ConsumerCodeAll = d.select("p:eq(3)").text();
         String ConsumerCode = ConsumerCodeAll.substring(ConsumerCodeAll.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
         String MembershipNumberAll = d.select("p:eq(4)").text();
         String MembershipNumber = MembershipNumberAll.substring(MembershipNumberAll.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
         String CompanyAddressAll = d.select("p:eq(6)").text();
         String CompanyAddress = CompanyAddressAll.substring(CompanyAddressAll.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
         String TelephoneAll = d.select("p:eq(8)").text();
         String Telephone = TelephoneAll.substring(TelephoneAll.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
         String WebsiteAll = d.select("p:eq(9) :not(span)").text();
         String Website = WebsiteAll.substring(WebsiteAll.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
         String EmailAll = d.select("p:eq(10) span").text();
         String Email = EmailAll.substring(EmailAll.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
         String ContactAll = d.select("p:eq(11)").text();
         String Contact = ContactAll.substring(ContactAll.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
         String ContactPositionAll = d.select("p:eq(12)").next("hr").text();
         String ContactPosition = ContactPositionAll.substring(ContactPositionAll.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
```

Comment: what the website you are trying to extract  this html part from it?

Answer (score 0):

You want to get Blank data(`String contact = null` or `String contact = ""`),when the 'Contact' p tag is empty. Is it Right?

According to your scrapping page, there is no class or id in `p` element. So, basically you can't identify specific information like 'Contact'.

My suggestion is "Select elements that contains the specified text".( [jsoup API - selector](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html)) It return `null` if none.

```
String contact = d.select("p:contains(Contact:)").get(1);
```

Or you can use `:matches(regex)`

```
String contact = d.select("p:matches(^Contact:.*)").get(1);
```

Plus, in Java convention,Variable should be initial lower case letter like 'contactAll'(it called by 'lower Camel case').
These articles might be help : 
[The Java™ Tutorials- Variables - Naming](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) / 
[Using Java Naming Conventions](https://www.thoughtco.com/using-java-naming-conventions-2034199)

Happy coding!